# Adding conditional attributes components in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use MUI tabs control.

So in each of my Tab Panel I have form fields. So there are some validations functions executing and I am keeping a status flag for each of the Tabs.

```
const [contextStatus,setContextStatus]=React.useState(true);
```

And here is my Tab header

```
       <Tab
          icon={<ErrorIcon />}
          iconPosition="end"
          label="Acquisition"
          {...a11yProps(1)}
        />
```

Here what I am trying to implement is I need the ErrorIcon to show there based when the above contextStatus boolean is false.

No idea how to achieve that..

Comment: Hi, I think you can implement the above functionality by just setting a ternary operator while passing the prop like `icon={contextStatus ? <ErrorIcon /> : <div></div>}`

Comment: a little bit shorter - `icon={contextStatus ? <ErrorIcon /> : <div />`